# Does JavaFX have something like SWT's Actions?

Tags: javafx, jface

I remember that SWT/JFace has a representation for actions that is independent of graphical user interface elements (such as a button or menu item). This way, when the interface changes, the underlying action model remains the same. For example, I may create an action "Find" that is detached from any particular menu or button.

I am not finding a corresponding notion in JavaFX 8. Does it have it?

[Here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/action/IAction.html)'s a page explaining SWT/JFace's Action. Note that it is different from an event, and therefore different from JavaFX's ActionEvent.

Comment: Can you add a link to your question which explains what these SWT Actions are?

Comment: Actions in Eclipse are replaced by commands

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no equivalent functionality in the core JavaFX libraries, though [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/) provides a [similar API](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/action/package-summary.html).

Comment: Thanks, didn't know ControlsFX. Looks great, lots of other goodies there!